# Darkening of sides of cup during render

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

In my Blender Guru doughnut scene, the **left** side of my cup is a little bit black. I can't understand what to do— is it a modelling error which I need to correct?
[image]
Notice the darkened side of the cup.

Comment: do you mean on the top left of the cup? It works fine here, I don't see the same result. You haven't packed your images though, I don't know if it would change anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your normal map is set to sRGB.

[image: shader setup of the cup glass]

It's twisting your normals. use Non-color